# Unable to create Documents collection in meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Trying to create a collection called "documents" and insert a document from main.js in my meteor application. When trying to execute the findOne method in the console window I get "Uncaught ReferenceError: Documents is not defined". I am using meteor version 1.10.2. I have mongo installed on my computer and its mongo shell version is 4.2.1. How do I enable my app to use mongo?

main.js

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';

Meteor.startup(() => {
  // code to run on server at startup

  this.Documents = new Mongo.Collection("documents");

  if(!Documents.findOne()) {
    Documents.insert({title:"my new documents"});
  }

});
```

Comment: Are you executing the `findOne` method in a mongo shell or in the browser console ?

Answer (score 1):

Documents is not defined because you assigned the collection to `this.documents`
Just define Documents like a normal variable

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';

const Documents = new Mongo.Collection("documents");

if(!Documents.findOne()) {
  Documents.insert({title:"my new documents"});
}

export { Documents }
```

---

To access `Documents` in the console, you need to import the module into the console (like you would in a file), except in the console, you do this with `require`:

```
require('/path/to/main').Documents
```

Note: this is only possible when `Documents` is exported

Alternatively, you can make it global by assigning it to `window` or `global`:

```
const Documents = new Mongo.Collection("documents");
window.Documents = Documents;
```

With globals you just need to be careful not to name other variables with the same name so you know what object you're handing

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Fred but that did not work. Same issue.

Comment: @larry8989, sorry, I missed that you were trying to access it from the console, I've edited the answer with how to do that